# How can I successfully connect the HIVE in docker's cloudera?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, hive, cloudera

I am the new learner in docker's cloudera.

I have set the docker engine as the following:

[image]
Then, I have created the the cloudera container by the following command:

`docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera  --privileged=true -v ~/Documents/class/datasets:/etc/spark/datasets -t -i -p 8888  4239cd2958c6 /usr/bin/docker-quickstart`

Then, the env would directly be the `[root@quickstart]` .
In order to make Spark and Hive work together, I need to copy the Hive configuration file into Spark’s configuration directory, I ran the following command in Cloudera image command terminal

`sudo cp /etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-site.xml /etc/spark/conf/`

Then, I tried to connect the Hive.

I ran `beeline`

and `!connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 cloudera cloudera org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver`

It returned the following error:
[image]

I have checked the status by `sudo service --status-all` and it returned:

[image]

Is it need all status to be TRUE? (since it occured the FAILED status when I was installing the cloudera container)

What should I do?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Running thirty-some services, including multiple databases, with manual network setup, is not at all a typical use for a Docker container.  If your environment needs things like manual iptables setup, a virtual machine is a much better match, won't require administrative-level controls over the host (be very wary of `--privileged`), and will probably be generally less finicky.

Comment: how can I successfully connect the HIVE ? `!connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 cloudera cloudera org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver`  still has the error

Comment: because this is a assignment for the student to understand how to connect hive and how to implement hive SQL and spark etc. The task come from the professor, I have no choice to choose other tools to work; therefore, I sill need to fix the bug :(